# Conversion from C++ to Delphi (simple)

Tags: c++, delphi, zeos

I have a function in C++ that I am attempting to replicate in delphi:

```
typedef double  ANNcoord;        // coordinate data type
typedef ANNcoord* ANNpoint;      // a point     
typedef ANNpoint* ANNpointArray; // an array of points 

bool readPt(istream &in, ANNpoint p) // read point (false on EOF)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        if(!(in >> p[i])) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

In Delphi I believe that I have correctly declared the data types.. (I could be wrong):

```
type
  IPtr =  ^IStream; // pointer to Istream
  ANNcoord = Double;
  ANNpoint = ^ANNcoord;

function readPt(inpt: IPtr; p: ANNpoint): boolean;
var
  i: integer;
begin

  for i := 0 to dim do
  begin

  end;

end;
```

But I cannot figure out how to mimic the behavior in the C++ function (probably because I do not understand the bitshift operator).

Also, I need to eventually figure out how to transfer the set of points from a Zeos `TZQuery` object to the same datatype - so if anyone has some any input on that I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
type
  ANNcoord = Double;
  ANNpoint = ^ANNcoord;

function readPt(inStr: TStream; p: ANNpoint): boolean;
var
  Size: Integer; // number of bytes to read
begin
  Size := SizeOf(ANNcoord) * dim; 
  Result := inStr.Read(p^, Size) = Size;
end;
```

There is no need to read each ANNcoord separately. Note that istream is a stream class, not an IStream interface, in C++. Delphi's equivalent is TStream. The code assumes the stream is opened for reading (Create-d with the proper parameters) and the current stream pointer points to a number (dim) of ANNcoords, just like the C++ code does.

FWIW `in >> p[i]` reads an `ANNcoord` from the input stream `in` to `p[i]`, interpreting `p` as a pointer to an array of `ANNcoords`.

### Update

As Rob Kennedy pointed out, `in >> myDouble` reads a double from the input stream, but the stream is interpreted as ***text*** stream, not binary, i.e. it looks like:

```
1.345 3.56845 2.452345
3.234 5.141 3.512
7.81234 2.4123 514.1234

etc...
```

There is, AFAIK, no equivalent method or operation in Delphi for streams. There is only `System.Read` and `System.Readln` for this purpose. Apparently **Peter Below** once wrote a `unit StreamIO` which makes it possible to use `System.Read` and `System.Readln` for streams. I could only find [one version](http://groups.google.com/group/borland.public.delphi.objectpascal/msg/d682a8b5a5760ac4?pli=1), in a newsgroup post.

It would probably make sense to write a wrapper for streams that can read doubles, integers, singles, etc. from their text representations. I haven't seen one yet.

Comment: The C++ code had the following:                                   while (nPts < maxPts && readPt(*dataIn, dataPts[nPts])) nPts++; Would your code fill the array (p) up in the same way? Or would it assign just 1 point?

Comment: I am not sure the array is a perfectly square array. It looks like it is rather an array of pointers to arrays with (dim) ANNcoords.

Comment: How would I then add `p` (ANNPoint) to `dataPts`(ANNPointArray)?

Comment: `TStream.Read` is not the equivalent function for this. The C++ code uses the `>>` operator to extract values from an `istream` into a `double`. That reads the stream *as text* and converts each token into a `double`. The Delphi code is reading the stream in binary mode to copy each eight-byte piece of the stream directly into each array element.

Comment: @Rob: Oops, it seems you are right. istream::operator>> reads text, not binary data. istream::read reads binary data.

Comment: @Rob: I have been thinking hard and even looking around everywhere, but I can't think of an equivalent. Ok, System.Read and System.Readln will do the trick, but there is nothing in TStream that allows you to read and convert text that way. Or what am I missing?

Comment: I have been using Lazarus/FreePascal instead of delphi. Are these  analogous functions? http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/objects/tstream.strwrite.html http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/objects/tstream.strread.html